# Child div's height exceeds parent div's height

Tags: html, css, joomla

I want to recreate a template for Joomla, but using this HTML code ([HTML at patebin.com](http://pastebin.com/9vRnR4tJ)) and this CSS code ([CSS at pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/2UhF7Xwz)), the wrapper div (parent) is rendered with a smaller height than the content div (child). I already used google, but adding a clear:both div or changing the height didn't work.

€: Only IE5.5 and 6 render the div's height as I want it to be.

Comment: what about if you add `overflow:hidden` to your parent div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kwJuT/embedded/result/

Comment: `overflow:hidden` will just cut off the table, but not expand the parent div. And thanks for adding this link to jsfiddle, I didn't know it yet.

Comment: The parent div must have height that's the reason it is not expanding as the child div. If you replace the parent div as `width:auto` then it should be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: ([Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/BvFFGkyb))

- I removed all the height styles from the CSS;
- floated the #content div so it wouldn't overlap the #nav;
- and added a .clearfix class to the #wrapper, which keeps the floated elements contained by adding some invisible content to the beginning and end of the #wrapper.

A .clearfix class is very useful when you are floating any elements. Simply apply it to the parent of the floated element.

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} /* works for all browser but IE 6/7 */

.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

.clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* fix for IE 6/7 (triggers hasLayout) */
```

You can read more about .clearfix [here](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/The-style/#clearfix).